# Is there a way to map a value in an object to the index of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, knockout.js

Prepending that a solution only needs to work in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari as a bonus.

-

I am trying to use an associative array for a large data set with knockout.  My first try made it a true associative array:

```
[1: {Object}, 3: {Object},...,n:{Object}]
```

but knockout was not happy with looping over that.  So I tried a cheating way, hoping that:

```
[undefined, {Object}, undefined, {Object},...,{Object}]
```

where the location in the array is the PK ID from the database table.  This array is about 3.2k items large, and would be iterated over around every 10 seconds, hence the need for speed.  I tried doing this with a splice, e.g.

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    self.myArray.splice(item.PKID, 0, new Object(item));
}
```

but splice does not create indices, so since my first PKID is 1, it is still inserted at `myArray[0]` regardless.  If my first PK was 500, it would start at 0 still.

My second thought is to initialize the array with `var myArray = new Array(maxSize)` but that seems heavy handed.  I would love to be able to use some sort of map function to do this, but I'm not really sure how to make the key value translate into an index value in javascript.

My third thought was to keep two arrays, one for easy look up and the other to store the actual values.  So it combines the first two solutions, almost, by finding the index of the object in the first example and doing a lookup with that in the second example.  This *seems* to be how many people manage associative arrays in knockout, but with the array size and the fact that it's a live updating app with a growing data set seems memory intensive and not easily manageable when new information is added.

Also, maybe I'm hitting the mark wrong here?  We're putting these into the DOM via knockout and managing with a library called isotope, and as I mentioned it updates about every 10 seconds.  That's why I need the fast look up but knockout doesn't want to play with my hash table attempts.

--
clarity edits:
so on initial load the whole array is loaded up (which is where the `new Array(maxLength)` would go, then every 10 seconds anything that has changed is loaded back.  That is the information I'm trying to quickly update.

--
knockout code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: myArray(), afterRender: setInitialTileColor } -->
    <div class="tile" data-bind="attr: {id: 'tileID' + $data.PKID()}">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Then on updates the hope is:

```
$.each(data.Updated, function (index, item) {
    var obj = myModel.myArray()[item.PKID];
    //do updates here - need to check what kind of change, how long it's been since a change, etc
}
```

Comment: You need to find items by their PK ID? Sort? Are the numbers/indices doing anything front-end, or do you just need them for retrieving data from the server?

Comment: First off what you've shown isn't valid syntax for a javascript array...post some of the actual json. Not 100% clear what you are working with. Also, do you control the API source output?

Comment: no, they're just arbitrary ones that won't change.  they have org IDs, but those are only going to matter if we keep the same system and never switch.  It's really just for quick look up, otherwise this turns into 9k loops per 10 seconds in the worst case, 4.5k loops average.

Comment: charlietfl: the first two are just examples and are what chrome spits out as arrays (though chrome spits out `undefined x 1`).

the output from the server is just the result of a sproc call, it comes back as a json array with the ID as well as things like name and such.

Comment: 3K items isn't large, have you even tried just using array of objects?

Comment: It's 3K now, but could easily be 15K in a short time.  We have tried with an array but it starts to freeze up after a while, especially if it's a large update and it needs to cycle through the arrays for a look up.  I mean, if there's even a 15 item update it's going to do 20k loops just on a look up if we're being optimistic.

Comment: `but knockout was not happy with looping over that. ` How were you trying to loop over it with knockout? Can you should that code. Perhaps your problem is there.

Comment: something is really wrong here. Worst case you could use webworkers to offload some processing but my guess  is you have a design flaw

Comment: Matt - it's a very simple `<!-- ko foreach: {data: myArray(), afterRender: setInitialTileColor } -->` where `setInitialTileColor` would hopefully use the quick look up to flag the correct elements.

Comment: charlietfl: how do you propose finding something in an array then?  Every 10 seconds I get items which have changed and I need to find them in the array and update them to keep the integrity of the knockout.

Comment: In your foreach, the 2nd argument to setInitialTileColor will be the data item. setInitialTileColor doesn't have to do a lookup to find it.
http://jsfiddle.net/rr9uLtzs/1/

Comment: Roy - right but there are other places (like on updates) where I do need to loop through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution how to populate array items with correct indexes, so it doesn't start from the first one (0 (zero) I meant)

just use in loop

```
arr[obj.PKID] = obj;
```

and if your framework is smart (to use forEach but not for) it will start from your index (like 500 in case below)

http://jsfiddle.net/0axo9Lgp/

```
var data = [], new_data = [];

// Generate sample array of objects with index field
for (var i = 500; i < 3700; i++) {
    data.push({
        PKID: i,
        value: '1'
    });
}

data.forEach(function(item) {
    new_data[item.PKID] = item;
});

console.log(new_data);
console.log(new_data.length); // 3700 but real length is 3200 other items are undefined
```

Comment: that works in regular javascript but knockout doesn't like that, I don't think.  If I try to do it that way and not with a method on the Array object (push, pop, splice) then it doesn't update correctly.  I suppose it might be worth it to initialize the array like that and then put it into knockout, rather than the other way around.

Comment: So I tried this way: 

    var arr = [];

    $.each(data.customersWithTickets, function (index, item) {
        arr[PKID] = new Object(item);
    });

    self.Data = ko.observableArray(arr);

and that ran into the same issue as the first one where the $data object on the knockout model was undefined.

Comment: could you please update you question to contain knockout code so we could see what do you want to achieve and based on this to help you with a solution, because the problem is in your question title, you are too deep in detail, but we should see the problem on high level of knockout, maybe it's a simple solution for your problem already exist.

Comment: updated!  I think the meat of my problem is I need to do a lot of "thinking" per change so adding the complexity of trying to find it but keeping it scaleable is a doozy.

Comment: I'm silly! My problem in this was that myArray[0] is undefined....since it starts at 1.  Adding a `<!-- ko if: typeof $data != "undefined"-->` flag around the rest of the knockout helps, but the initial load is now really slow haha

Comment: I am sure for these types of data manipulation and re-rendering it's better case to use React.js but it's just my opinion.

Comment: Sorry Eugene, this is for work so I don't really have a lot of choices.  I will keep it in mind for personal projects though, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an easy problem to solve. I'm assuming you've tried (or can't try) the obvious stuff like reducing the number of items per page and possibly using a different framework like React or Mithril.

There are a couple of basic optimizations I can suggest.

1. Don't use the framework's each. It's either slower than or same as the native Array method `forEach`, either way it's slower than a basic for loop.
2. Don't loop over the array over and over again looking for every item whose data has been updated. When you send your response of data updates, send along an array of the PKIds of the updated item. Then, do a single loop:

.

```
var indexes = []
var updated = JSON.parse(response).updated; // example array of updated pkids.
for(var i=0;i<allElements.length;i++){
    if(updated.indexOf(allElements[i].pkid)>-1)
        indexes.push(i);
}
```

So, basically the above assumes you have a simple array of objects, where each object has a property called `pkid` that stores its ID. When you get a response, you loop over this array *once*, storing the indexes of all items that match a pk-id in the array of updated pk-ids.

Then you only have to loop over the `indexes` array and use its elements as indexes on the `allElements` array to apply the direct updates.

Answer (score 1):

If your indexes are integers in a reasonable range, you can just use an array. It does not have to be completely populated, you can use the `if` binding to filter out unused entries.

Applying updates is just a matter of indexing the array.

http://jsfiddle.net/0axo9Lgp/2/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the [publish-subscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern. Have each item subscribe to its unique ID. When an item needs updating it will get the event and update itself. [This library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) may be helpful for this. It doesn't depend upon browser events, just arrays so it should be fairly fast.